# PHP DOM/xpath check element span class value

Tags: php, html, xpath

Within a curl request I have a html table that has the below structure. I now want to extract only table rows that contain a span element with the empty class and not the ones with the class="subcomponent".
I successfully tried Xpath to find the elements with the empty class but how to do I get the entire `<tr>` or even better specific `<td>` nodes that contain Version and Partnumber.
Thanks in advance.

```
<table>
...
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <span class="">Product</span>
        </td>
        <td>Version</td>
        <td>Partnumber</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <span class="subcomponent">Component</span>
        </td>
        <td>Version</td>
        <td>Partnumber</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My PHP code

```
$doc = new DOMdocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($page);
$doc->saveHTML();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$query ='//span[@class=""]';
$entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo $entry->C14N();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the table rows themselves using SimpleXML, you can use the following:

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_string('<table>...</table>');

$rows = $sxml->xpath('//tr[td/span[@class=""]]');

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  echo "Version: ", $row->td[3], ", Partnumber: ", $row->td[4];
}
```

The XPath works by selecting all `<tr>` tags that have a child `<td>`, which itself has a child `<span>` with a blank class.

In the loop, you need to access the child cells of each row by number, since your sample doesn't indicate that they're labelled any other way. I'm assuming a table structure won't change too often though, so that should be fine.

See https://eval.in/860169 for an example.

## Alternative DOMDocument Version

If you're fetching a full webpage, which won't necessarily be well-formed, you might need to use `DOMDocument` as you have in your first example. It's a bit less clean to access the child-elements, but something like the following will work:

```
$doc = new DOMdocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($page);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$rows = $xpath->query('//tr[td/span[@class=""]]');

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');

    $version = $cells->item(3)->nodeValue;
    $partNumber = $cells->item(4)->nodeValue;

    echo "Version: {$version}, Part Number: {$partNumber}", PHP_EOL;
}
```

See https://eval.in/860217

Comment: I get the table through a curl command and have stored it in $page. How would I make that work with your code?

Comment: If the page is well-formed, you should just be able to use `$sxml = simplexml_load_string($page);` instead of the first line. I've also edited the answer with a DOMDocument, in case that doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you - the alternative DOMDocument approach works great!

Answer (score -1):

I would use next XPath expression:

```
//td[text()="Version"] | //td[text()="Partnumber"]
```

Which gives me:

```
Element='<td>Version</td>'
Element='<td>Partnumber</td>'  
Element='<td>Version</td>'
Element='<td>Partnumber</td>'
```